# Experimental Typography Design Help

Tags: adobe-photoshop, typography, posters, clipping-mask

Does anyone know any tutorials on how to achieve these poster designs. My professors want us to design our project like this but never gave us any links on how to achieve this. My first mind is to use Photoshop Clipping Mask but I can be wrong. Your thoughts and suggestions will be greatly appreicated!

[image: Sample 1]

[image]

Comment: In vector software, you'd use your pathfinder tools to cut/slice things up.

Comment: I believe there are several tutorials on the web about how to use masks, in several different ways, and your question requires a quite basic knowledge of the software of choice; therefore I'll vote to close this question as off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

A clipping or layer mask will achieve this in Photoshop, as will a Clipping Mask in Illustrator.

Answer (score 1):

Illustrator: outline type, create shape in angle, pathfinder, than clean up and save.

Comment: Also possible with Indesign, but you will need layers.